# How can i resolve this PDOException for this update query?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I want to do a function that would let my change a password by using 4 inputs:

```
$utente (a user id that comes from a session)
$pswold (the old password)
$pswnew (the new password)
$rippswnew (the repeated new password)
```

The first part of the function looks if $pswnew and $rippsnew are the same, a simple if that works.

The second part look into the database if the old password corrispond to the one of the user in session and works too.

The part that gives me problems is the function Passwordupdate.
This is the complete error that is shown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Portaleambv3\class\Utente.php:111 
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Portaleambv3\class\Utente.php(111): 
PDOStatement->execute() #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Portaleambv3\class\Utente.php(89): 
Utente->Passwordupdate('1', 'd6f644b19812e97...') #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Portaleambv3\process_cambiopsw.php(34): 
Utente->Changepassword('1') #3 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Portaleambv3\class\Utente.php on line 111
```

And this is my function

```
public function Changepassword($utente) {
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();

    $pswold = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pswold', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $pswnew = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pswnew', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $rippswnew = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rippswnew', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    if ($pswnew === $rippswnew) {
        $query = "Select UTE_ID, UTE_USERNAME, UTE_PASSWORD from utenti" .
                " where UTE_ID=:utente and UTE_PASSWORD=:password ";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':utente', $utente, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $statement->bindValue(':password', $pswold, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $statement->execute();

        $ute_id = $statement->fetchColumn(0);
        if ($ute_id != NULL) {
            $db = null;
            $statement = null;
            $this->Passwordupdate($utente, $pswnew);
            return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["error"] = 'Message';
            header('Location: impostazioni.php');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION["error"] = 'Message';
        header('Location: impostazioni.php');
        return false;
    }
}

private function Passwordupdate($utente, $pswnew) {
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    $query = "UPDATE utenti " .
            "SET UTE_PASSWORD=:pswnew " .
            "where UTE_ID=:uteid";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':uteid', $utente, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $statement->bindValue(':pswnew', $pswnew, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $statement->execute();

    $_SESSION["error"] = 'Password is changed';
    header('Location: impostazioni.php');
}
```

The line 111 is the one with $statement->execute(); in the Passwordupdate function and 89 is where the Passwordupdate function is called.
And i tried to run the update statement directly in phpmyadmin and works too.

EDIT
Resolved

EDIT2:
I had already watched that question and tried to remove the quotes but didn't worked. The problem was in the spaces.
So, sorry, but I don't think that the answer of the question that this question is being marked as duplicate of could have helped me.

Comment: `' :pswnew '` <-- get rid of the quotes.

Comment: I tried but nothing changes

Comment: Which line is 111? And please update your code with the change you just made.

Comment: I explained that at the end of the question. It's where I execute the update query.

Comment: So you did. Next issue, you now have no space between `:pswnew` and `where`.

Comment: Why are you using the PDO::FETCH_OBJ on bindValue method? It should  be PDO::PARAM_* constants.

Comment: Leave a space here `UPDATE utenti` after utenti and before SET,same at WHERE

Comment: " $statement->bindValue(':utente', $utente, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $statement->bindValue(':password', $pswold, PDO::FETCH_OBJ); "

what are you fetching here?

Comment: Ok, it now works. The issues were in the spaces. I now feel like an idiot. Question edited.

Comment: Can you explain what exatly that error says in a comprehensible language? I was imagining something much more complex when i saw it.